# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2005 installed on Win7 virtual machine

Tags: sql-server-2005, virtual-machine

I am not able to connect to a SQL Server 2005 hosted on a Win7 virtual machine. I am new to VM, can someone help me locate the problem?

I am able to connect another SQL server which is installed on the local machine.

Comment: Many things can go wrong: can you ping your virtual machine? Is the firewall open for port 1433? Is your server configured for remote connections? ... are the first things that come to mind.

Comment: TO add to @DavidBrabant's comment. Please ensure that the you have full connectivity with the machine first.

Comment: I am able to ping VM using ip address, firewall is also disabled, remote connection are also enable.

Comment: I am able to ping VM by using ip address only and not by machine name? Am I missing something?

Comment: try to use VM Network Bridged Adapter, turn off firewall or add rules, connect via IP or IP with port ex. 192.168.0.100,1433

Answer (score 1):

When you say you can't connect - that can mean a lot of things - really you need to be much more specific.

In addition to the comments and answers already here - If you're having trouble connecting to it in Sql Server Management Studio - you should open Configuration Manager on the VM itself and make sure that Shared Memory and Named Pipes are enabled (open the SQL Server Network Configuration node in the tree).

For example, SQL Server Express instances are configured by default to reject the kind of remote connection that SSMS wants to open by default.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your connection string (for reference):
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Second you need to add an exception in the guest machine firewall or completely disable it (port 1433 is for sql tcp/ip access).

this works fine for me:

```
SQLConn.ConnectionString = "Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;
Initial Catalog=mySQLServerDBName; User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword"
```

good luck